# Can not execute flutter app when I run it

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

When I run the flutter app nothing happens in android emulator, the vscode console shows this error :

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Samsung Galaxy S8 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timeout of 120000 reached waiting for exclusive access to file: C:\Users\13\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-5.6.2-all\9st6wgf78h16so49nn74lgtbb\gradle-5.6.2-all.zip
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:61)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timeout of 120000 reached waiting for exclusive access to file: C:\Users\13\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-5.6.2-all\9st6wgf78h16so49nn74lgtbb\gradle-5.6.2-all.zip
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:61)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.685], locale en-US)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[!] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[√] VS Code (version 1.52.1)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

by the way both dart and flutter plugins are installed.

Comment: your android emulator isn't open, hence it displays `! No devices available`.

Comment: I repeated that command many times while android emulator is opened but the same problem.

Comment: as it says, you did not install flutter and dart plugin, to do so,  [check here](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/editor)

Comment: already installed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter throwing error, Timeout of X reached waiting for exclusive access to file: Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67072304/flutter-throwing-error-timeout-of-x-reached-waiting-for-exclusive-access-to-fil)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is a caching problem. Try following steps.

1. open your project.
2. open terminal.
3. execute `flutter clean` command.
4. execute `flutter run` command.