# Flutter throwing error, Timeout of X reached waiting for exclusive access to file: Gradle

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle, gradle-plugin

```
Launching lib\main.dart on SM G615F in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timeout of 120000 reached waiting for exclusive access to file: C:\Users\Me\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-6.7-all\cuy9mc7upwgwgeb72wkcrupxe\gradle-6.7-all.zip
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:61)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timeout of 120000 reached waiting for exclusive access to file: C:\Users\Shaad\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-6.7-all\cuy9mc7upwgwgeb72wkcrupxe\gradle-6.7-all.zip
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:61)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

Can You help me Fight this issue?
I am Getting Gradle task *assembleDebug* error, also When I Run Flutter on Physical Device it Takes so much time to run and execute.

I want to seek help in this.

Answer (score 15):

This could be caused by broken `gradle` installation or slow internet.

**Solution**:

Delete the **`.gradle`** folder located at **Windows**: `C:\Users\<user>\.gradle` or  **Mac**: `/home/<user>/.gradle`

and then run the flutter app again.

It might take a little longer because **gradle** dependencies will be  downloaded again. Don't disconnect your device.

Comment: This is correct answer for question and needs to be marked as answer. I had same problem and it solved it!

Answer (score 4):

#### This is how to fix this.

- Just delete the `.gradle` folder in your user directory
- The command in linux or MacOS is  `rm -r $HOME/.gradle/`
- Then open your project directory and then navigate to android folder
- Finally, run `./gradlew`
- This will force gralde to redownload all dependencies needed
- That's it ,

### Happy coding ✨

Answer (score 0):

Try to install gradle manually (https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-bin.zip), and unzip it

Open `<path_to_flutter_app>/android/gradlew`

Find: `CLASSPATH=$APP_HOME/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar`
and replace with: `CLASSPATH=<path_to_downloaded_gardle>/gradle-4.6/lib/gradle-launcher-4.6.jar`

Find: `exec "$JAVACMD" "${JVM_OPTS[@]}" -classpath "$CLASSPATH" org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain "$@"`

and replace with: `exec "$JAVACMD" "${JVM_OPTS[@]}" -classpath "$CLASSPATH" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "$@"`

flutter run