# Timeout of 120000 reached waiting for exclusive access to file

Tags: gradle, visual-studio-code, minecraft, minecraft-fabric

I am trying to create a minecraft mode in visual studio code and I am trying to import the minecraft and fabric API code but it give me this error

Could not install Gradle distribution from [gradle](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.8.3-bin.zip).

> Timeout of 120000 reached waiting for exclusive access to file:
> C:\Users\nivco.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-6.8.3-bin\7ykxq50lst7lb7wx1nijpicxn\gradle-6.8.3-bin.zip

Can someone please help me solve this problem? I also try to create my mode through this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_JZ7bnk3oiM&t=180s

Also here is my gradle properties is case there is anting wrong there:

```
Done to increase the memory available to gradle.
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1G

Fabric Properties`enter code here`
check these on https://fabricmc.net/use
minecraft_version=1.16.5
yarn_mappings=1.16.5+build.6
loader_version=0.11.3

Mod Properties
mod_version = 0.0.1
maven_group = ShimiTavori.electricity
archives_base_name = electricity

Dependencies
currently not on the main fabric site, check on the maven: https://maven.fabricmc.net/net/fabricmc/fabric-api/fabric-api
fabric_version=0.32.5+1.16
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter throwing error, "Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67072304/flutter-throwing-error-exception-gradle-task-assembledebug-failed-with-exit-c)